# How should I check if object is null or not?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SavedGamesSlots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject saveSlotPrefab;
    public float gap;

    private Transform slots;
    private string[] imagesToLoad;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        string imagesFolder = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/Saved Screenshots");
        if (!Directory.Exists(imagesFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesFolder);
        }

        imagesToLoad = Directory.GetFiles(imagesFolder, "*.png");

        slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform;

        if (imagesToLoad.Length > 0 && slots != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.Length; i++)
            {
                var go = Instantiate(saveSlotPrefab);
                go.transform.SetParent(slots);

                Texture2D thisTexture = new Texture2D(100, 100);
                string fileName = imagesToLoad[i];
                go.GetComponent<RawImageInfo>().FolderAndFileName = fileName;
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                thisTexture.LoadImage(bytes);
                thisTexture.name = fileName;
                go.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = thisTexture;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I'm checking in this line if slots is not null :

```
if (imagesToLoad.Length > 0 && slots != null)
```

The problem is that I'm getting exception null already on the line before :

```
slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform;
```

The reason is that the object with the tag "Slots Content" is disabled when the game start and I want it to be disabled when the game start but I also don't want to get this null exception. Then how should I make the null checking ?

I tried also :

```
if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform != null)
            slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform;

        if (imagesToLoad.Length > 0 && slots != null)
```

But still getting the exception null on the check :

```
if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform != null)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform;
```

`FindGameObjectWithTag` can return `null` if it doesn't find such an object, then the `transform` reference will fail.

Just split this into two lines:

```
Transform theTransform;
slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content");
if(slots != null)
{
    theTransform = slots.transform;
}
```

There are other ramifications in your code now that `theTransform` might not have what you're looking for.